# Read xml with namespace in IE, FF and chrome

Tags: xml, namespaces

I have the below xml response with namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response status="200">
  <ns3:op xmlns="http://xxx.com/details/" 
              xmlns:ns2="http://xxx.com/mgmt/" 
              xmlns:ns3="http://xxx.com/list/">
    <ns2:ntfs count="140">
      <ns2:ntf>
        <ns2:Nid>4687807</ns2:Nid>
      </ns2:ntf>
    </ns2:ntfs>
  </ns3:op>
</response>
```

I need to parse this and get the Nid value for each row. I tried using getElementsByTagName(ns3:op) but it doesnt work in safari. 
Also tried using
xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("/response/op/ntfs"); 
But it is not working in FF.
is there any way where i can read the response independent of namespace and browser.

Hi,

My output xml might change and the elements may or may not have namespace prefixes.
So i need to parse the xml irrespective of the namespace.
How can i achieve this?
This is little urgent to me , any pointers would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

With namespaces you need to use `getElementsByTagNameNS` with the namespace URI

```
document.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://xxx.com/list/', 'op')
```

However this apparently doesn't work in IE earlier than 9. A commonly recommended cross browser solution is [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/), a JavaScript library which implements the XPath approach in a way that works on more browsers:

```
var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(....);
xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", 'xmlns:ns3="http://xxx.com/list/"');
xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
var op = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/response/ns3:op");
```

Comment: @ Ian ..Thanks for the reply. But getElementsByTagNameNS does not work in IE 8. Is there any way the code works in all browsers like IE , FF and chrome...

Comment: @later2013 I've done a bit more digging and edited my answer with another suggestion.